# Shuffle polyominos in a grid

Tags: algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, shuffle

I have a 2d array that contains polyominos of lengths 1 to 4, i want to shuffle their position AND rotation.

For example:

```
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,X,0,0,0,0,3,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,X,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

First, 0s are empty spaces, and numbers are polyominos. There are four of them: one tetromino "L" made by 1s, one tromino "L" made of 2s, and one monomino made by one 3. I want to shuffle this grid, changing their position and rotation without loosing their structure.

Second, though 0s are available spaces, Xs aren't and cant be shuffled.

I'd be happy if someone can help me solve the first part of the problem, but if there is anyone smart (or bored) enough to solve also the second part, it'll really appreciated because this stuff gets way over my head.

Edit:

The problem can also be seen as placing N polyominos in a 2d grid of fixed size.

Comment: What have you tried, do you have any code that is or isn't working?  I have ideas, and have built a tetris like game of my own in the past!

Comment: I didn't try anything yet, I have some ugly ideas that include brute-forcing, but I would prefer to have an elegant solution for this, since it's for a mobile game and I don't want it to hang while shuffling the puzzle.

Comment: Does the shuffling happen only at the beginning of the game, or does it happen as they are in real-time play?

Comment: I'm generating the puzzle in its finished state, and I need to shuffle it once, before showing it to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that rather than having a board the way you have it, you should actually store a list of pieces, and their rotation and position on your board.  The way you are storing it right now, it is much more difficult to manipulate because you have essentially finalized the data onto the board as a single data set.

If you like, you can store the board with a set of booleans (simply to take up less space in memory) where a true correlates to your "X" and a false correlates to an un-utilized space.

Then I would randomly choose a rotation for each piece before placement.

After you know the finalized randomized rotation, you can move through your LIST of pieces, generate a list of all placement locations possible, and simply choose one of those locations randomly.  You will have to generate this potential placement list separately for each piece, as once a piece is placed, you will not be able to place another piece on top of it!

The trick here is to separate your board data from your pieces data so that you can manipulate the pieces more easily.

Comment: Well, I actually have the game data structured more o less like you are describing it. I have a list of pieces, I can rotate each of the separately, and so on.

Comment: I'm worried for what would happen if the puzzle is too crowded:

[1,0,0,0,8,8]
[1,0,0,4,0,8]
[1,1,0,4,4,4]
[0,0,9,9,0,0]
[5,3,3,3,0,0]
[5,0,6,6,6,0]
[5,0,0,7,7,7]

And while trying to place each piece one by one may cause the algorithm to get stuck with the last one because there isn't any possible position left.

I asked the question using a grid because to me looks like a problem that someone should have already faced.

Comment: Thats the beauty in the answer I provided, is that you test to see if the last piece CAN even be placed or not before actually placing.  If it absolutely can't be the end, you may be able to swap it with another piece that has already been placed.

Comment: After some more googling, seems like I'm looking for a fillomino solver, I'll accept your answer because it pointed me in the right direction.